# Identify and Rerun particular events in Axon

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, axon

We were looking into rerunning handpicked events from axon. A use case would be along the lines of the following.

If the user's registration event failed even though the command was successful, we want to rerun that particular event for that specific event handler(s).

We looked into using the tracking event processor, but that seems to be of replaying a set of events FROM a specific point in time. However, in our case, if there were 100 events yesterday, we would only want to rerun a particular event in the middle.

At the moment we are in migration of migrating to Axon and as such have decided to go with SubscriptionEventProcessors predominantly as it is more synchronous (i.e. errors are propagated up the command handler). And we do understand that subscription processors are stateless, as in they only process what they received via the event bus.

So I am assuming that we cannot use the tracking processor? and instead, we need to load the particular event and re-push it to the event bus?

How could we achieve this? (With or without the above suggestion)

Also with regards to identifying exceptions, we are thinking of using aspects and logging and reading the particular log line for exceptions. However we did notice a tracing module for axon and spring boot. https://github.com/AxonFramework/extension-tracing However it is mentioned to be in beta and there was not much reference documents we could find yet either. Is there a better more axon based solution to this as well?

Comment: A small comment on my side: extension-tracing is not in Beta anymore =)

Comment: Nice, just noticed the readme was updated. Also is there extension specific reference docs?

Comment: See if the [official doc](https://docs.axoniq.io/reference-guide/extensions/tracing) helps, if not, there is a blog post about it [here](https://blog.trifork.com/2019/03/18/distributed-tracing-in-an-axon-application).

Comment: A bit offtopic, so we managed to use jaeger with axon and spring boot autoconfigure successfully, however when we tried to use spring sleuth (which is springs distributed tracing library on top of brave) we included brave-opentracing, spring-cloud-starter-sleuth and spring-cloud-sleuth-zipkin dependencies. But axon traces does not get sent to jaeger in this configuration, any ideas on what the config should be?

Comment: Right figured it out we believe, though will need to test a bit more. The BraveTracer was not getting created so we had to create it manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be quick about it, I would use a similar response as I have posted on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59199109/axon-replay-trackingevent-related-to-some-aggregateidentifier-using-axon-4/59389715#59389715) question.

The rehash my response over there quickly, it can be summarized by:
Create a Query Model containing the required `@EventHandler` annotated methods to "re-handle", which you'd provide as input to Axon's `AnnotationEventHandlerAdapter` constructor. You would call the subsequent `AnnotationEventHandlerAdapter` with a filtered event stream based on the requirements you have. As a result, the Query Model will be updated to the format you need.

Thus instead of performing it as a form of query because the users requires that information, you would perform the operation upon an exceptional case. Regardless, you will still form the Query Model anew, but just based on a specific set of events.

By the way, when it comes to the choice of Event Processor, I'd still go for the `TrackingEventProcessor`. Yes it means an event failure would not issue a rollback, but in essence the event states it has occurred. Thus rolling back because something else fails handling that event is incorrect; the command still succeeded, so it should stay as such too.

Lastly, you are looking for logging logic. The Tracing Extension you've shared has just recently been pulled from it's beta status and thus can be used safely. Next, basic logging can already be achieved by configuring the `LoggingInterceptor` as a `MessageHandlerInterceptor` and `MessageDispatchInterceptor` (documentation on this can be found [here](https://docs.axoniq.io/reference-guide/configuring-infrastructure-components/messaging-concepts/message-intercepting)). And if you are looking to introduce Aspect logic: Axon has a similar mechanism to tie into each message handler out there. Have a look at the `HandlerEnhancer`/`HandlerEnhancerDefintion` on [this](https://docs.axoniq.io/reference-guide/appendices/message-handler-tuning/handler-enhancers) page.

Hope all this helps you out @MilindaD!

Comment: Okay so after going on the rabbit hole on googling "AnnotationEventHandlerAdapter" I came across another answer you answered which talks about using `eventStore.readEvents` which is what we are trying out at the moment. Combining that with some spring reflection to manually trigger the `@Service` appropriate event handler method via function call (since payload Is of the same class).

Comment: Also with regards to the tracing extension, is there any extension specific references? Or did I misunderstand and are the links you provided related to the extension?

Comment: The `AnnotationEventHandlerAdapter` is a core component indeed, so I understand you'd have to go down a rabbit hole to follow this. AxonIQ is having plans for a form of dev-portal, which should include FAQ like this. And, asking question about this is always a good thing of course! AxonIQ is active on StackOverflow and their own usergroup -> https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/axonframework

Comment: When it comes to tracing, there are three main points of info I could provide. Firstly, the GitHub page: https://github.com/AxonFramework/extension-tracing. Secondly, the Reference Guide: https://docs.axoniq.io/reference-guide/extensions/tracing. And lastly, a blog about it, written by the guy who introduced the Tracing Extension: https://blog.trifork.com/2019/03/18/distributed-tracing-in-an-axon-application/

Comment: A bit offtopic, so we managed to use jaeger with axon and spring boot autoconfigure successfully, however when we tried to use spring sleuth (which is springs distributed tracing library on top of brave) we included `brave-opentracing`, `spring-cloud-starter-sleuth` and `spring-cloud-sleuth-zipkin` dependencies. But axon traces does not get sent to jaeger in this configuration, any ideas on what the config should be?

Comment: Right figured it out we believe, though will need to test a bit more. The BraveTracer was not getting created so we had to create it manually.

Comment: Happy to hear you figured it out @MilindaD. The one thing the `TracingAutoConfiguration` in Axon's Tracing Extension requires is the existence of a `Tracer` bean. Having the `BraveTracer` missing in your setup indeed sounds like the culprit to me.